# Load Balancing in Bluemix using custom domain and DNS SRV records

Tags: dns, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to do a load balancing of the application in bluemix using custom domain and SRV record in DNS manager. I created my own doamin `ccbluemix.dynu.com` and added that as custom domain to bluemix. I created application in US region and created a route with custom domain `myapp.ccbluemix.dynu.com` Then I deployed same application in uk region and created a route with custom domain `myapp.ccbluemix.dynu.com` there as well.

Now whenever user hits this route I want to do a load balancing between US and UK region so that alternate requests are served by us and uk regions.

For this I created SRV records like

```
_http._tcp.ccbluemix.dynu.com SRV eu-gb.mybluemix.net [Priority: 0] [Weight: 50] 10
_http._tcp.ccbluemix.dynu.com SRV mybluemix.net [Priority: 0] [Weight: 50] 10
```

But nothing is happening and I'm not able to access the application using custom route at all.

If I create 'A' record like this cc-load-bal-app.ccbluemix.dynu.com A 75.126.81.68

I can access the app using custom route but obviously it always ends up hitting US server.

How can I achieve load balancing using SRV records? Is something wrong with creating SRV records here?

I also read that you need to have 'A' records for the host name you are using in SRV record.

So I tried to creat 'A' records for bluemix.net and `eu-gb.bluemix.net` but did not help.

Can someone help?

Comment: Is this a web application, served through browser over HTTP?

Comment: Yes its a simple web application. Infact currently I'm using Java Cloudant Boilerplate. My main aim is to achieve load balancing

Comment: You may want to review : Configure and run a multiregion Bluemix application with IBM Cloudant and Dyn, might give you good hits on where to start http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-multi-region-bluemix-apps-with-cloudant-and-dyn-trs/index.html

Comment: Thanks @vmovva.

Actually I started with the same link but don't want to use Dyn because it only offers 7 days free subscription for DNS managers.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, web browsers [do not support SRV records](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14328), for all sorts of reasons.

You may achieve some sort of load balancing with [Round Robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) but that is a poor replacement for proper load balancing, which is very far from trivial to set up for geographically distributed servers, and usually requires proprietary services from large infrastructure providers (for example [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-complex-configs.html), [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-multi-region-bluemix-apps-with-cloudant-and-dyn-trs/index.html) or [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/cross-region-example))

Comment: Thanks!!! My stuff is not working because of this probably. So I need to find different and better option for doing it